# Background Image of webpage not showing in html

Tags: html, css

I am currently creating a website for a school assignment and have had trouble inserting a background image.
Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Like a Veggie</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="veggie.css">
</head>

<body>
<table width="80%">

<td width="200" valign="top">
<table width="200">
           <tr><td><a href="index.html"> Home <a/></td></tr>
           <tr><td><a href="aboutme.html"> About Me <a/></td></tr>
           <tr><td><a href="timetable.html"> Time Table <a/></td></tr>
           <tr><td><a href="mylinks.html">Wierd links</td></tr>

        </table></td>

</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
body {
    background-image: "background.png"
}
```

Thanks in advance

Note: I would rather if the image wasn't from a url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if your background image is being served up locally, the syntax is the same.

```
body {
  background-image: url("background.png");
}
```

..should work for you!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that definitely helped!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where your background.png located. If it locates with the css file, you can use `background: url('background.png');`
Even though your image does not come from a url, you still have to use this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your CSS

```
 background-image: url("paper.png");
```

Replace `paper.png` with the name of your image.